# Use IronPython to access COM object in a browser?

Tags: com, ironpython

I am trying to use a COM object by IronPython in a browser.
I have tried the following code in ipy.exe and it works fine:

```
from System import Type, Activator
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application"))
```

But if I use the code a a browser like this:

```
<html>
<script type="text/python"> 
from System import Type, Activator
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application"))
</script>
</html>
```

It just doesn't work.

I want to know if there are restrictions when using IronPython in a browser. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight, which is what allows IronPython in the browser has strict security.  Silverlight's sandbox requires the IronPython code to run in an internet domain (localhost included), but not the local domain (directly from the file-system).  You might find some more information from Jimmy Schementi's [blog](http://blog.jimmy.schementi.com/2010/03/pycon-2010-python-in-browser.html).